# Sumo días en JavaScript en un for pero me salta días

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un bucle `for` para que me sume días y me pongan su respectivas fechas en una matriz.

```
const currentWeek = [ 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
let dayOfWeek = [];

for(let i = 0; i < currentWeek.length; i++) {
  dayOfWeek.push(new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + i)))
}
```

Funciona bien, solo que me salta algunos días como el 28, el 2 y me manda hasta el 5 de febrero cuando solo me tiene que imprimir hasta el domingo 30.

```
"dayOfWeek": [
        "2022-01-26T04:59:46.874Z",
        "2022-01-27T04:59:46.874Z",
        "2022-01-29T04:59:46.874Z",
        "2022-02-01T04:59:46.874Z",
        "2022-02-05T04:59:46.874Z",
        "2022-02-10T04:59:46.874Z"
    ]
```

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar para qué es el propósito de esto?, tal vez podría ayudarte a manejar de mejor manera los días de la semana para que evites `const currentWeek = [ 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']` que esto sea inválido la siguiente semana

Answer (score 3):

Estás sumando a la fecha en curso 1, 2, 3, 4 y 5 días de manera acumulativa.

Eso significa que la primera vez lo harás bien, la siguiente saltarás un día, la siguiente dos, luego tres y por último cuatro días.

Es debido a esta línea:

```
date.setDate(date.getDate() + i))
```

Cada vez que lo ejecutas estás sumando `i` días a la fecha que tenga en ese momento `date` y, tenlo en cuenta, `date` se actualiza a esa nueva fecha porque estás usando `setDate()`.

Para hacerlo correctamente puedes hacer ir incrementando la fecha en un único día:

```
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1))
```

Y, por lo tanto, ejecutar el siguiente código:

```js
const currentWeek = [ 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
let dayOfWeek = [];

let date = new Date();
for (let i = 0; i < currentWeek.length; i++) {
  dayOfWeek.push(new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)))
}

console.log(dayOfWeek);
```

Resultado:

```
[
  "2022-01-27T08:06:22.363Z",
  "2022-01-28T08:06:22.363Z",
  "2022-01-29T08:06:22.363Z",
  "2022-01-30T08:06:22.363Z",
  "2022-01-31T08:06:22.363Z",
  "2022-02-01T08:06:22.363Z"
]
```

También puedes hacerlo sumando el número de días a la fecha base, sin actualizarla, de la siguiente manera:

```javascript
  let fecha = new Date(date);
  /* Sumamos "i" días a la fecha inicial */
  fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + i);
```

Puedes ver el funcionamiento a continuación:

```js
const currentWeek = [ 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
let dayOfWeek = [];

let date = new Date();
for (let i = 0; i < currentWeek.length; i++) {
  let fecha = new Date(date);
  /* Sumamos "i" días a la fecha inicial */
  fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + i);
  dayOfWeek.push(fecha);
}

console.log({dayOfWeek});
```